# Не могу сдвинуть иконку(человек) вправо через слова iphone 14 pro shop

Tags: html, css

На картинке изображена и описана проблема, помогите решить, может я где туплю

Прилагаю код со ссылкой на гитхаб
https://github.com/HahDasModell/14proShop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полагаю с таким вопросом вам никто не поможет, не качественный вопрос. Не видно стилей

Comment: https://github.com/HahDasModell/14proShop/blob/main/index.html
https://github.com/HahDasModell/14proShop/blob/main/styles.css
Вот ссылки на код, просто, понятно.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну... Каков привет, таков и ответ. Никто не будет разбираться с гитхабом, что-то себе ставить и прочее. Стилей в вопросе не видно, поэтому пальцем в небо:

У вас у **.nav-bar** стоит `display: flex`. Предлагаю почитать для начала: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox. А если хотите быстрее, то попробуйте у **.nav-bar** добавить `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

Comment: У меня такое чувство, что у него и так там стоит что-то смещающее иконку влево, так в html видно, что иконка должна быть справа при обычном display: flex; Я думаю у него там стоит на иконке float: left;